# How to turn object values into new array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, sorting, object

I am trying to simplify the following state:

```
{ 
  "name": "bulbasaur", 
  "picture": "https://raw", 
  "height": 7, 
  "weight": 69, 
  "types": [
    { 
      "slot": 1,
      "type": { 
        "name": "poison", 
        "url": "https://poke" 
      }
    }, 
    { 
      "slot": 2, 
      "type": { 
        "name": "grass", 
        "url": "https://poke" 
      }
    }
]}
```

into something like this:

```
{ 
  "name": "bulbasaur", 
  "picture": "https://raw", 
  "height": 7, 
  "weight": 69, 
  "types": [ "poison", "grass" ] 
}
```

Also, I would like to mention that I have an array with 151 of these. Not every object contains two types; some only contain one.

I believe that is the reason most of what I have tried so far does not work. Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: so array map is what you need and I assume the `=` is really `:`

Answer (score 0):

Try using map

```js
let obj={ name: "bulbasaur", picture: "https://raw", height: 7, weight: 69, types : [{ slot: 1, type: { name: "poison", url:"https://poke" }}]};
obj.types=obj.types.map( Type => Type.type.name);
console.log(obj.types);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want, you will need to add this snippet in a loop for you dataset and have it pushed into a new array:

```js
const Obj = { 
  "name": "bulbasaur", 
  "picture": "https://raw", 
  "height": 7, 
  "weight": 69, 
  "types" : [{ 
   "slot": 1, 
   "type": { 
    "name": "poison", 
    "url":"https://poke" 
 }}, { 
    "slot": 2, 
    "type": { 
     "name": "grass", 
        "url":"https://poke" 
    }}
]};

const newObj = {
  ...Obj,
  types: Obj.types.map((el) => el.type.name),
}

console.log(newObj)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve what I needed by using the logic provided by Ma'moun othman.

```
  "name": "bulbasaur", 
  "picture": "https://raw", 
  "height": 7, 
  "weight": 69, 
  "types" : [{ 
    "slot": 1, 
    "type": { 
        "name": "poison", 
        "url":"https://poke" 
    }}, { 
    "slot": 2, 
    "type": { 
        "name": "grass", 
        "url":"https://poke" 
    }}
]};

const newObj = {
  ...Obj,
  types: Obj.types.map((el) => el.type.name),
}

console.log(newObj)
```